# Expecting 'STRING', got 'EOF'

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to create a config.gateway.json file for a Ubiquiti firewall and I need to upload the file to it. I go to the website jsonlint.com and try to run the following into it:

```
{
    "LOAD_BALANCE": {
        "description": "LOAD_BALANCE",
        "rule": {
            "2000": {
                "action": "modify",
                "modify": {
                    "lb-group": "wan2_failover"
            },
            "source": {
                "address": "172.16.7.0/24"
            },
            "interfaces": {
                "bridge": {
                    "br0": {
                            "aging": "300",
                            "bridged-conntrack": "disable",
                            "hello-time": "2",
                            "max-age": "20",
                            "priority": "32768",
                            "promiscuous": "disable",
                            "stp": "false"
                    }
                },
                "load-balance": {
                    "group": {
                        "wan2_failover": {
                            "flush-on-active": "disable",
                            "interface": {
                                "br0": {
                                    "failover-only": "''"
                                },
                                "eth0": "''"
                            },
                            "lb-local": "enable",
                            "lb-local-metric-change": "enable"
                        },
```

but I get the error `Expecting 'STRING', got 'EOF'`

If one of the fine Java gurus could help me I'd appreciate it!

Comment: You json file incomplete

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JSON has some unbalanced curly brackets. Maybe this is what you're after:

```
{
    "LOAD_BALANCE": {
        "description": "LOAD_BALANCE",
        "rule": {
            "2000": {
                "action": "modify",
                "modify": {
                    "lb-group": "wan2_failover"
                },
                "source": {
                    "address": "172.16.7.0/24"
                },

                "interfaces": {
                    "bridge": {
                        "br0": {
                            "aging": "300",
                            "bridged-conntrack": "disable",
                            "hello-time": "2",
                            "max-age": "20",
                            "priority": "32768",
                            "promiscuous": "disable",
                            "stp": "false"
                        }
                    },

                    "load-balance": {
                        "group": {
                            "wan2_failover": {
                                "flush-on-active": "disable",
                                "interface": {
                                    "br0": {
                                        "failover-only": "''"
                                    },
                                    "eth0": "''"
                                },
                                "lb-local": "enable",
                                "lb-local-metric-change": "enable"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```